# Is there a way to allow users to enter new Enterprise keywords when managing items and documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, custom-list, enterprise-keywords

I have a custom list and a document library inside our modern communication online site collection. and for both of them we allowed "Enterprise Metadata and Keywords Settings". Now when we upload a document or create a list item >> we can only reference existing terms inside the  "Enterprise keywords" column,

[image]

so is there a way to allow users to create new terms if what they type inside the above field does not match any existing term?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Under the Library/List Settings, check under Advanced Settings.  The option to Allow management of content types must be set to Yes to allow users to add options on the fly.